# Testing multiple associations with shoulda, should belong to using foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, shoulda

I'm trying to test model associations, but when I run the test, it  never passes.

Tried following the documentation, but had no success.

My entity Story has 3 associations with the same entity: User

```
class Story < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :writer, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :reviewer, class_name: 'User'
end
```

Associations defined on the User end:

```
has_many :created_stories, class_name: 'Story',
    foreign_key: 'creator_id'
  has_many :written_stories, class_name: 'Story',
    foreign_key: 'writer_id'
  has_many :reviewed_stories, class_name: 'Story',
    foreign_key: 'reviewer_id'
```

Test:

```
class StoryTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  should belong_to(:creator).class_name('User').with_foreign_key('creator_id')
  should belong_to(:writer).class_name('User').with_foreign_key('writer_id')
  should belong_to(:reviewer).class_name('User').with_foreign_key('reviewer_id')
end
```

Although, when I run the test, I get:

```
Error:
StoryTest#test_: Story should belong to reviewer class_name => User. :
Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '' for key 'index_users_on_email'
```

Already tried, adding the foreign key on Story model, still had the same results.

Comment: the error happens for the 3 associations, not only for reviewer

Answer (score 0):

I added the `foreign_key` in the `Story` model too, and my tests passed:

```
class Story < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: "creator_id"
  belongs_to :writer, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: "writer_id"
  belongs_to :reviewer, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: "reviewer_id"
end
```

Also, my `story_spec,rb` looks like this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Story, type: :model do
  context "associations" do
    it { should belong_to(:creator).class_name('User').with_foreign_key('creator_id') }
    it { should belong_to(:writer).class_name('User').with_foreign_key('writer_id') }
    it { should belong_to(:reviewer).class_name('User').with_foreign_key('reviewer_id') }
  end
end
```